# How to use range variable from prompt response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make this simple function where I get the range & value I want to fill from the prompt response (so basically autofill given range with given value). But I get 'Exception: Range not found'. How can I use the response from prompt to work as range?

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi ();
  var response = ui.prompt("Enter Range:",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if(response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){
    var inputvalue = ui.prompt("Set Value:",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var givenvalue = inputvalue.getResponseText();
    ss.getRange(response.getResponseText).setValue(givenvalue)
  }else if(response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that the reason of your issue of `Exception: Range not found`, is due to `getRange(response.getResponseText)`. In this case, the method of `getResponseText` is not run. Please add `()` like `ss.getRange(response.getResponseText()).setValue(givenvalue)`, and test it again. I thought that there might be some duplicated questions in this case. But I couldn't find them. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike you were right, that was the problem apparently - I didn't even notice. Or to be honest I was't too sure on the rest of it so thought the problem might be elsewhere! thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, for documentation purposes, please consider accepting the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880560.

Answer (score 1):

Posting for documentation purposes.

As mentioned by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870276/how-to-use-range-variable-from-prompt-response-answered/69880560#comment123507886_69870276), since you missed the `()` in `response.getResponseText()`, you are passing the method [getResponseText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getresponsetext) instead of the string value returned by this method as a parameter for [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). Since this is not a valid parameter for this method (it would require a string), you are getting this error.

#### Solution:

Replace this:

```
ss.getRange(response.getResponseText).setValue(givenvalue)
```

With this:

```
ss.getRange(response.getResponseText()).setValue(givenvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A Dialog to Enter Data into a Spreadsheet

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const r1 = ui.prompt("Enter Range in A1Notation(Remember to include Sheet Name):", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r1.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let r2 = ui.prompt("Enter value to place in range:", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (r2.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      let v = r2.getResponseText();
      ss.getRange(r1.getResponseText()).setValue(v)
    }
  }
}
```

[ui promt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#prompt(String))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).